# Is there a better, built-in, FASTER system to compose textures by a sequence of textures on top of each other?

Tags: unity, textures

Say I have these textures:

[image: Body]
[image: Cloth]
[image: Hat]

*Disclaimer: These textures belong to RPG Maker MZ and nobody has rights to use them outside their client, so never use them for production deployments but only to experiment.*

And say I am using Unity 2020.3 (although by its nature, this code works on any 2017+ version of Unity). I wanted to make something that composes them by successive pasting (with transparency) generating something like this:

[image]

And so after looking insigts in the Unity forum, I grabbed an algorithm and came with my own version (it is quite similar, almost the same, but adapted to my structure):

```
    [RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
    public class SampleBlitSprite : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
        
        [SerializeField]
        private Texture2D[] textures;

        private void Awake()
        {
            spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            // I'm not sure about the performance of doing this.
            // The algorithm works, but I need a more performant
            // way to do this, if any. I did not stress-test this
            // solution, even when the pooling system may mitigate
            // a good part of the impact. Perhaps there is a more
            // performant way of doing this.
            //
            // For this script to work, all the textures in the
            // array must be either created dynamically or marked
            // as "Read/Write enabled" while importing the texture
            // in the TextureImporter Editor settings.
            Texture2D tex2d = new Texture2D(144, 192, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
            Color[] pixels = tex2d.GetPixels(0, 0, 144, 192);
            for (int index = 0; index < pixels.Length; index++)
            {
                pixels[index] = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            foreach (var texture in textures)
            {
                Color[] sourcePixels = texture.GetPixels(0, 0, 144, 192);
                for (int index = 0; index < pixels.Length; index++)
                {
                    if (sourcePixels[index].a > 0)
                    {
                        float a = sourcePixels[index].a + (1 - sourcePixels[index].a) * pixels[index].a;
                        Color c = (sourcePixels[index] * sourcePixels[index].a +
                                   pixels[index] * pixels[index].a * (1 - sourcePixels[index].a)) / a;
                        c.a = a;
                        pixels[index] = c;
                    }
                }
            }
            tex2d.SetPixels(0, 0, 144, 192, pixels);
            tex2d.Apply();
            spriteRenderer.sprite = Sprite.Create(tex2d, new Rect(48, 144, 48, 48), Vector2.zero, 48);
        }
    }
```

This algorithm does not check appropriate rects and dimensions, but it should do in a production environment. This one is just a proof of concept that actually worked to me and the samples I use are of those dimensions.

**Now my inquiry is**: Is there any more preformant / best practice method of composing textures? This one works, but I'm not sure how much will it work when many objects need to do this in the same environment. I'm just experimenting, right now.

Comment: Presumably you considered making a `RenderTexture` and using `Graphics.Blit()` to perform the compositing on the GPU instead of the CPU?

Comment: I tried Blit (as the name of the class suggests) in first place, against a RenderTexture. BUT it completely replaced the contents on each iteration: The successive .Blit calls ended with only the hat (which is the last texture) being rendered.

Is there any thing similar to .Blit or an alternate configuration to a .Blit call (other than the default) that pastes on top without replacing the contents entirely?

Comment: Yes, you pass the current composition in progress as one argument, and use a material whose shader blends _MainTex with a second texture of your choosing, using the blend operation of your choosing.

Comment: Is there any default shader that I could use to generate this? (it is the first time I _need_ to deal with shaders at all).

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but it's pretty trivial to write one. It's just two texture samples and a lerp.